# How to pass WebAPI Controller data such that Posted Model has access at Binding/Deserialization or Validation Time

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

Consider this WebAPI Controller where some meta data is retrieved at instantiation.

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private readonly MetaData _metaData;

    public MyController(IService service) // IService is injected via Unity Container DI
    {
        _metaData = service.GetMetaData();
    }

    [ValidateModel]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] PostModel model)
    {
        // do something
        return new ResponseMessageResult(null);
    }
}
```

And suppose the Post action's PostModel class is defined as below:

```
public class PostModel : IValidatableObject
{
    ComplexObject Data { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        // do something, using _metaData
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // validate, using _metaData
    }
}
```

I want my PostModel to have access to the MyController _metaData object ideally by the time OnDeserialized() is called, but I would settle for at least by the time Validate() is executed.

I have considered:

- ActionFilter- impossible, as model binding/validation occurs before
  ActionFilter execution
- Custom ValueProvider/ModelBinder- I thought perhaps these together would allow me to define the StreamingContext used in OnDeserialized() and set its Context property to _metaData.  But even if this is possible, I could not figure out a way to do it correctly.
- MessageHandler- I think a per-route message handler is not ideal, but I could use dependency injection to retrieve the _metaData and then...append this object data to the posted data? This feels hacky and I'm not very enthusiastic about this type of solution.
- Dependency Injection- I could give PostModel a reference to the service during its own instantiation, however the Controller and the Model live in separate projects, with the Model project not having a Unity Container dependency at present.  Instead, it relies on the Controller project and other referencing projects to use their own DI to pass any required data.

Perhaps there is some kind of action-level Attribute I'm not aware of that would benefit me here, or maybe one of the above was on the right track?   I have to believe there is a way to pass/access dynamic server-side data during deserialization or at least by validation of the Model that I'm just not aware of or thinking of the proper way to do.

Two additional notes:

- I am using Asp.Net WebAPI and do not have access to Core WebAPI attributes, filters, etc.
- The Post action is in ProjectA but PostModel is in ProjectB.  ProjectA references projectB, but the inverse is not true.  ProjectB does not presently have a dependency on Unity Container DI.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why not inject the IService into the PostModel, or something that inherits from PostModel?

Comment: That's a good idea, however, the way my solution is structured I have several projects that reference ProjectB (where the PostModel lives), all of which pass in the necessary information to ProjectB themselves.  For this reason I've been able to avoid ProjectB needing a dependency on Unity Container DI.  My preference is to keep ProjectB agnostic of the dependency injection container and rely on the other projects to provide it the info it requires.  I mentioned this loosely under additional notes but did not make it explicit so will edit my question.  Thanks for your comment though!

Answer (score 3):

You can use an IModelBinder to both deserialize and validate your PostModel.  Doing it this way, you'll have access to your Controller instance during the deserialization.  This code is fairly rough, but you should get the idea.

IModelBinder Implementation

```
public class PostDataModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(PostDataModel))
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
          // Get the content of the request, deserialize into your model object
          Task<string> bodyTask = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          PostDataModel vm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PostDataModel>(bodyTask.Result);

          // Get an instance of your IService and get metadata
          var service = (IService)actionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IService));
          var metadata = service.GetMetadata();

          // this is how you would get the Metadata directly from your controller as long as it was accessible
          //var metadata = ((IMetadata)actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller).Metadata;

          // do stuff with metadata to validate your object however you wish
          vm.PopulateValidationErrors();

          // return true if you were able to deserialize this object, false if you couldn't 
          return vm != null;
        }
        catch {
          // do logging
          return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Use IModelBinder globally by adding it to the Register method of WebApiConfig
`config.BindParameter(typeof(PostDataModel), new PostDataModelBinder());`

Comment: Suggestion. Using the action context get the dependency resolver and resolve the service to access the metadata instead of trying to extract it from the controller. Other than that, this is a good approach.

Comment: I was trying to not change the OP's code too much, but I definitely like that better.  I modified the code to show how you would get the metadata from the service as opposed to the controller.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion! This looks promising and I will look to implement it shortly and write back with my results.  One question off the bat however- suppose my PostModel has 3 SubModelA/B/C properties, each of which would normally be deserialized and validated by its respective SubModel class implementation.  Will this approach still allow those Models to deserialize and validate themselves or will I now have to validate the whole object tree here manually?  ...I suppose since binding takes place before validation, after BindModel() returns, normal execution will validate as before?

Comment: The IModelBinder interface is a hook into to ASP.NET MVCs process and so you are telling ASP.NET to use this to bind your model instead of using its default process.  BindModel() returns a Boolean saying whether or not the bind was successful.  That said, when you deserialize the body using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject it should deserialize the SubModelA/B/C properties as well.  As for validation, the way I would do it is have the PostModel's validate method call the validate methods of any properties that have one, so I guess I'm saying you'd validate the whole tree in here.

Comment: This was a step in the right direction but it turns out that validating a complex object graph is very tedious to do in a custom model binder, so I decided not to go this route afterall.  I also tried a custom Formatter but using that method does not include access to an ActionContext.  I'll eventually get around to writing up an answer that explains what I tried and what didn't work for me but I'm still looking for the perfect solution. That said, you answered my question with sound advice that may help others so I'm glad to award you the bounty.  Thanks!